# The edit program is not working in MS-DOS

Tags: windows-xp

`edit.com` is not working. When running `edit` at command-prompt, it is giving the error

> The system cannot execute the specified program.

Comment: For those saying it’s not being found; it *is* being found or else they would be asking [this](http://superuser.com/questions/94014/dos-edit-command-no-longer-recognized-or-working) instead.

Comment: See here https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/1174-fix-the-system-cannot-execute-the-specified-program

Answer (score 2):

This error means that either the file/program is corrupt or the environment in which it is running is not correct. File corruption is the most common cause.

Since in this case, corruption *should* not be the cause, then what might be happening is that the NTVDM is damaged or there is not enough memory left to run it. What *might* also be happening is that you are running a copy of a different file called `edit.com` instead of the one that comes with Windows, so as sgmoore mentioned, try entering the fully-qualified-path: `%systemroot%\system32\edit.com`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your paths might be wrong or if you are using a floppy disk it might not have been included. Can you give us more information of what version of DOS you are running and how you are getting to MS-DOS?

Comment: Nope. That would have given the error `'edit' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Answer (score 0):

Edit.com should be in your system32 directory so %windir%\system32\edit.com should start it.

Comment: Yes, and it *is* being run, hence the lack of `…not recognized…` error message.

Answer (score 0):

Verify if default values for "Path" are in your environment variables (<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Break</kbd>, *Advanced*). "C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;" must be there. Do not forget ";" to separate the paths.

If it does not solve it, try restoring your Windows installation with the CD.

Comment: The path has nothing to do with it. If it were not found, the error message would have been `'edit' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` not `the system cannot execute the specified program.`

Answer (score 0):

Pardon me, but could it be so simple as when you state MS-DOS it really is the Command-Line (Cmd) windows in windows, where the (presumably) 16bit edit.COM cannot longer run?